# How do I run the tests that are part of an installed/installing Cabal package?

Tags: haskell, testing, cabal, package-managers, cabal-install

I have a Haskell package I've installed from Hackage, using `cabal` and would like to run the tests suites that are part of the package, but it isn't clear to me from the `cabal` documentation how to do this.

I've tried:

```
cabal install --reinstall --enable-tests --run-tests the-package
```

and its various combinations and permutations, but no tests seem to run: I get no report about the test running, and none of the output that I know the test should produce is generated.

How do I run the tests that are part of an installed `cabal` package, or a package that I'm in the process of installing?

Comment: Maybe `cabal test the-package`?

Comment: @recursion.ninja: I tried that too but that seemed way off the mark: `Package has never been configured. Configuring with default flags. If this fails, please run configure manually. cabal: No cabal file found. Please create a package description file <pkgname>.cabal`

Comment: You're right, it's not that simple. See my answer for a more robust solution.

Comment: There may be [a known bug](https://github.com/gelisam/hawk/issues/141).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `--run-tests` flag does not appear to be working in the current version of `cabal`. The `--enable-tests` flag no longer runs tests as a new feature of `cabal`. Until the issue is resolved you can ***manually*** verify that a package passes it's test suite by doing the following:

1. Use `cabal` to download the package source
2. Use `cabal` to build the package in a sandbox
3. Use `cabal` to run the tests in the sandbox

Use this series of cabal commands to run the test for `the-package`:

```
cabal get the-package
cd the-package*
cabal sandbox init
cabal install --dependencies-only
cabal configure --enable-tests
cabal build
cabal test
cd ../
rm -r the-package*
```

Or use this equivalent one-liner:

```
cabal get the-package && cd the-package* && cabal sandbox init && cabal install --dependencies-only && cabal configure --enable-tests && cabal build && cabal test && cd ../ && rm -r the-package*
```

Comment: Yes, that part I get. But is there no way to simply run the tests on an installed package *in situ*? What do `install --enable-tests` and  `install --run-tests` even do — nothing?

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius Are you *sure* the package has a test suite in its `.cabal` file? I `cabal install --run-tests` on a package (`tasty`) which I know has no test suite associated with it and it did not output an failure/warning message that there were no test to run. It just silently finished.

Comment: Yes, [it's there](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/crypto-enigma-0.0.2.0/src/).

Comment: I just tried with `cabal install megaparsec --run-tests` [which also has a test suite](https://github.com/mrkkrp/megaparsec/tree/master/tests) and it *also* finished without running tests. Very strange, maybe a `cabal` bug?

Comment: Yeah, maybe. Certainly nothing even remotely like what's described in the documentation is happening.

Comment: My answer should give you a method to run the tests independently and verify that they are all passing, but according to [this GitHub issue conversation](https://github.com/haskell/cabal/issues/1647) the `--run-test` flag should make the independent build & run unnecessary.

Comment: Can I do the with no side effects. Just delete the directory after?

Comment: Yup, just add a `cd ../ && rm -r the-package*` command at the end. The sandbox is in the directory. Delete the directory and the sandbox install is gone!

Comment: I had saw that related issue. I hope this is resolved in the next version of `cabal`. They should really prioritize this fix because *verifying an installation* is a pretty desirable function of *any* package installer.

Comment: Agreed! It's too bad, really. I'm just learning Haskell, and there are a lot of things about it and its ecosystem that are pretty (surprisingly) much in disarray (compared with, say, Python).

Comment: This answer is outdated since `sandbox`es have disappeared from `cabal`.  I don't know a good answer myself, see https://github.com/haskell/cabal/issues/7267.

Answer (score 0):

The answer below no long works as noted in its comments. The following works for me with cabal 3.6.2:

```
cabal get the-package
cd the-package*
cabal v2-test
```